# Suggestion for a contact management database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, innodb

I am currently designing a contact management database for a chamber of commerce. The goal of the database is to store all the **person** (except our own staff), all recorded **companies** (regular companies and member of the chamber), **addresses** of the person and companies, **tasks** that the staff are currently responsible for, a list of our staff (**user**) and the **roles** within the chamber.

---

### Business Rules

- one `person` works for one `company`
- one `company` have multiple `person`
- `person` and `company` can have multiple `address`
- one `company` can be in multiple `industry`
- one `industry` can have multiple `company`
- one `company` can have multiple `membertype`
- one `membertype` can have multiple `company`
- one `user` can play multiple `role`
- one `role` can be assigned to mutliple `user`
- one `user` can have multiple `task`
- one `task` can be worked on by multiple `user`
- one `task` can target multiple `person`
- one `person` can be targeted by multiple `task`
- one `person` can only be added by one `user`
- one `user` can add multiple `person`
- one `company` can have 0 or 1 `parent_company`
- one `parent_company` can have multiple child company

I have come up with the following design and it has undergone some changes:

### [image]

### Issue

- Are there better ways to display the `user-task-person` relationship?
- For example, if a `person` can have only one `email` but can have multiple `tel`, should I make an extra table just for `tel` while `email` is still in the `person`table? Would it considered to be "unclean"?
- For the table `membertype`, should `company_id` and `typename` both be PK?
- How does this schema look now? Are there still some normalisations to be done?

---

I'm a newbee at database, there are definitely some design flaws or errors, it would be nice if you guys could give me some suggestions so that I can correct and improve this design. Thank you ^~^

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be asked at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @symcbean maybe you should first check what is **on-topic** on codereview.

Comment: I have: If you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas:

Best practices and design pattern usage
Security issues
Performance
Correctness in unanticipated cases

Comment: @symcbean and where is the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is that while all primary keys are defined as Int some foreign keys or references are defined as varchar.

1. company in contact table
2. user_role in user table
3. parent_company in company
4. added_by in user table

Also role_id is length 10 while all other primary keys are 11.
Personally I would prefer capitalised table names, User, Company etc

*Update for the edited version:*

You might want to create a table for phone, mail,fax etc say `contact_info` that could contain a string field holding the contact info and a type field (email, phone, fax,...). This way you could store several phone numbers for instance, if you want to limit email to one you could either leave it in the `person` table and not allow it here or have a business rule to only allow one email row in `contact_info`.

This table could also be useful for `company` if you want to store email or phone numbers for the `company` like contact@somecompany.com or the number to the company switchboard

> For the table membertype, should company_id and typename both be PK?

Yes

*Second update*
About the address solution:
Shouldn't the `address` table contain enough info to make each address unique, I can understand that a company can have more than one address but should it allowed for two companies to have the same address (by that I mean the same row in the database) so maybe it should be changed to a one-to-many from `company` and ´address´ but a one-to-one in the other direction.
I also think it could be good to have some kind of label in the two address-link tables so one can easily identify an address like "home", "work", "Office", "Warehouse"...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! If I want to create the `contact_info` table, the PK of this table should just be `person_id` right?

Comment: you probably want to give it its own id and use person_id as a FK to person.